# What code should I write in Drop off? ANYLOGİC

Tags: simulation, anylogic

What code should I write in Drop off?
The Simulation Scenario is as follows: There are 7 passenger stroke riding stops in total. There are also passenger arrivals to all 7 stops. Every two minutes a bus arrives and takes the passengers from the stop, lowering the passengers who want to get off. My problem starts exactly here. For example, how will I determine the passengers to land at the 3rd stop? I want 10% of passengers boarding at the first stop to drop 30% of passengers boarding at the second stop.
I did not know what to write in the drop off section to do so.

I tried this way. I have appointed passengers from each stop as agents separately. Maybe I could write it that way, but it gave an error when writing to drop off.

[general view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu2GG.png)     [error location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0wcD.png)

Comment: Welcome to SOF, happy to help. But your question is too brief and unclear. Please edit to add some details and clarify what you actually want to do :)

Comment: I am trying to simulate a subway. will take and drop passengers. Separate passengers are boarded from each stop. For example, I want to determine who will land at the third stop. 30% of the first stop, 20% of the second stop

Comment: cool, but this does not help with the problem. What is your current code trying to do, what error do you see, if any, ...? Really hard to help, please edit your question and add more info

Comment: thank you for answer. I will edit question. This is the first time I have used this program for a project. That's why I don't know much. I had previously worked on the Arena program.

Comment: better, thx. However, this is still confusing: "I want 10% of passengers boarding at the first stop to drop 30% of passengers boarding at the second stop" What does that mean?

Comment: I have a hard time explaining English, it is a bit complicated to explain.  I want 10% of passengers boarding at the first stop to get off 30% of passengers boarding at the second stop from the bus at the 3rd stop.  this is a public transport bus system

Comment: There are 7 stations in my project.  Passengers arrive at 7 stations. With the pick up ,I collect passengers at the first and second stations.  When I arrive at the third station, I want to drop off 10% of the passengers I pick up at the first station and drop off  20% of the passengers I pick up at the second station.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarifications.

Easiest way would be to store where pedestrians were picked up. Add a variable "myPickUpStation" to your pedestrian agent type (ensure to have a custom type).

Also, add a collection "myPedestrians" to your bus agent type. Fill it in the pickup so the bus knows who he has.

Then at dropoff, you can first query all peds in the bus who were picked up at station 1:

`findAll(container.myPedestrians, p -> p.myPickUpStation == 1)` (1 is just an example)

And then, take 10% of that group's size:

`0.1 * findAll(container.myPedestrians, p -> p.myPickUpStation == 1).size()`

Obviously, you will need to round that to a proper int

Comment: pleasure, @BeginnerAnylogic. If the answer helped, please mark it as "useful" (small up arrow next to it) so others can benefit from finding the answer in the future.